# How to sort column fields in Django model.object.values()

Tags: django, django-models

I am using this

```
objects = Model.objects.values('var1', 'var2', 'var4')
```

IN template i use

`{% for fieldname in object.keys %}<th>{{ fieldname }}</th>{% endfor %}`

But the field names appear in arbitrary order like

```
var4---var1----var2
```

I want them to appear like i provided in function

```
var1---var2----var4
```

is this possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just use `values_list`, which returns tuples and change your template accordingly.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

If for whatever reason, you want to keep using dict-s, and want an "automagical" solution, you'd have to do quite a bit of work:

1. Subclass Django's `ValuesQuerySet`, name it for ex. `OrderedValuesQueryset` and change it's `iterator` method to use `OrderedDict` http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict
2. Create a `Queryset` subclass which
   in it's `.values` method returns an instance of 
   your `OrderedValuesQuerySet`
3. Create a custom `models.Manager`
   class which in it's `get_query_set`
   method uses your custom `QuerySet`
   from 2.
4. Set the custom Manager to be used in your model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

Now what you are trying to do will work automatically on that model. You can also set the custom manager to a different attribute than `objects`, to also keep the default manager available.

Comment: i need to get the fieldNames i.e database column name. can get that with values_list

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather how to sort a Python dictionary, because this is what `values()` returns. Python dictionaries by definition do not have an ordering.

[See this blog post](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/)

Comment: But my fields don't have any sorting criteria , or i have to change my database field names by inserting some sort characters. Is there any other way